# When accessing a website (Glosbe.com) via json API special characters don't decode

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, decoding

When accessing this Glosbe.com via their API the following code isn't able to decode special characters or apostrophes.

As an example, it prints `perch&eacute;`, instead of `perché`. When inspecting the website source it says that the charset is utf-8. Any ideas?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
import json

url = ' http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=fra&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=chat&pretty=true'


weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = weburl.read().decode('utf-8') 

theJSON = json.loads(data)
print(theJSON)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site appears to give you data with HTML entities. Decode the HTML entities with:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

def unescape_entities(value, parser=HTMLParser()):
    return parser.unescape(value)

def process(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, list):
        return [process(v) for v in ob]
    elif isinstance(ob, dict):
        return {k: process(v) for k, v in ob.items()}
    elif isinstance(ob, str):
        return unescape_entities(ob)
    return ob

theJSON = process(theJSON)
```

Demo:

```
>>> theJSON['tuc'][0]['meanings'][-1]
{'language': 'fra', 'text': 'Mammif&egrave;re carnivore, f&eacute;lin de taille moyenne au museau court et arrondi, domestiqu&eacute; ou encore &agrave; l&#39;&eacute;tat sauvage (Felis silvestris).'}
>>> theJSON = process(theJSON)
>>> theJSON['tuc'][0]['meanings'][-1]
{'language': 'fra', 'text': "Mammifère carnivore, félin de taille moyenne au museau court et arrondi, domestiqué ou encore à l'état sauvage (Felis silvestris)."}
```